# How do i read the values of a returned pointer from ctypes?

Tags: python, arrays, c, pointers, ctypes

I am currently struggling with ctypes. I am able to convert a python list to a float array and give it to the C-function. But i can't figure out how to return this array from the C-function back to a python list...
Python-Code

```
class Point(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_= [("a", ctypes.c_float * 4),
               ("aa", ctypes.c_int)]

floats = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0] 
FloatArray4 = (ctypes.c_float * 4)
parameter_array = FloatArray4(*floats)

test1 = clibrary.dosth
test1.argtypes = [ctypes.c_float * 4, ctypes.c_int]
test1.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Point)
struc = test1(parameter_array, 9)

p = (struc.contents.a)
print(p)
clibrary.free_memory(struc)
```

The C-function basically puts the parameter_array into a structure ant returns the structure..
C-Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct a{float *a;
        int aa;
        } ;

struct a *dosth(float *lsit, int x){
    struct a *b = malloc(200000);
    b -> a = lsit;
    b -> aa = 3;
    return b;
}
void free_memory(struct a *pointer){
    free(pointer);
}
```

Output of print(p) in Python is :

```
<__main__.c_float_Array_4 object at 0x000001FE9EEA79C0>
```

How do i get access to those values?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: sorry, didn't know that..

Comment: "a" in the C struct is a pointer to float (or float array). To match this, in the ctypes Structure it must be a "ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)". Same for the argument type of the ctypes call.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can access the singular values now with p[i]! Is there a way to save the values of those pointers into a python list?

Comment: Use a slice. `p[:4]` will build a list of the first 4 values, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slicing a `ctypes` pointer will generate a Python list of the contents.  Since a pointer has no knowledge of how many items it points to, you'll need to know the size, usually through another parameter:

```py
>>> import ctypes as ct
>>> f = (ct.c_float * 4)(1,2,3,4)
>>> f
<__main__.c_float_Array_4 object at 0x00000216D6B7A840>
>>> f[:4]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Here's a fleshed-out example based on your code:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

struct Floats {
    float *fptr;
    size_t size;
};

API struct Floats *alloc_floats(float *fptr, size_t size) {
    struct Floats *pFloats = malloc(sizeof(struct Floats));
    pFloats->fptr = fptr;
    pFloats->size = size;
    return pFloats;
}

API void free_floats(struct Floats *pFloats) {
    free(pFloats);
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

class Floats(ct.Structure):
    _fields_= (('fptr', ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)),  # Pointer, not array.
               ('size', ct.c_int))  # Used to know the size of the array pointed to.
    # Display routine when printing this class.
    # Note the slicing of the pointer to generate a Python list.
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Floats({self.fptr[:self.size]})'

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.alloc_floats.argtypes = ct.POINTER(ct.c_float), ct.c_size_t
dll.alloc_floats.restype = ct.POINTER(Floats)
dll.free_floats.argtypes = ct.POINTER(Floats),
dll.free_floats.restype = None

data = (ct.c_float * 4)(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
p = dll.alloc_floats(data, len(data))
print(p.contents)
dll.free_floats(p)
```

Output:

```
Floats([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
```